# How do I score people on the Religious Orientation Scale?

Tags: social-psychology, religion

Where can I find the scoring and analysis of the intrinsic-extrinsic religious orientation scale given by Allport and Ross ([1967](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/bfa1/e5d350b1307ca9796f86495af668e9758e4f.pdf)). I'm unable to find it anywhere.
There is also a religious orientation scale by Gupta and Mishra (2007).

### References

Allport, G. W., & Ross, J. M. (1967). Personal religious orientation and prejudice. *Journal of personality and social psychology, 5*(4), 432. doi: [10.1037/h0021212](https://doi.org/10.1037/h0021212)

Comment: To help, I have edited your question to add in reference information for Allport & Ross (1967), could you please [edit] your question to add a reference for Gupta & Mishra (2007)?  I can't seem to find it on Google Scholar

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Gupta & Mishra as I cannot find the paper you are referring to, but [Allport & Ross (1967)](https://doi.org/10.1037/h0021212) on page 436 (page 5 of the pdf) points out that the full Religious Orientation scale has been deposited with the American Documentation Institute. You need to:

> Order Document No. 9268 from ADI Auxiliary Publications Project, Photoduplication Service, Library of Congress, Washington, D.C. 20540

I couldn't find the document on the [Library of Congress catalog](https://catalog.loc.gov/index.html), but it doesn't necessarily mean they don't have it.

You can have a web chat with a librarian  or use their general inquiries form by going to https://www.loc.gov/rr/askalib/ask-contactus.html

Comment: Thankyou! This really helps. I'll get in touch with the American Documentation Institute. :)